# Minifilter intercept network share enumeration

Tags: windows, wdk, minifilter

As the title says, how is this possible? Basically I want to intercept calls from [NetShareEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum) function same way as one would intercept calls to ReadDirectoryChangesW via IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL pre/post routines. Is filesystem minifilter enough for the task? Is there a major/minor function to register pre/post callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

NetShareEnum is not file system operation.
I think it's impossible with file system minifilter driver.